# SQL - how to select the last 5 values regardless of records

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I need to smash records so i have the most recent 5 values of each field excluding nulls and blanks. the expected out come would produce a table as such:

1. HT | WT  |  BMI  |    BP  | HR | RR
2. 72 | 148 | 20.07 | 120/70 | 68 | 16
3. 72 | 152 | 20.61 | 120/80 | 68 | 16
4. 72 | 154 | 20.88 | 120/68 | 70 | 16
5. ...

   here is a sample data set ordered by date already. [image]

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the last five rows, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Does the data have an ID# of the individual, and a date/time for each row?  How are we to determine "the last 5", "the most recent 5" ???

Comment: i left out a column, which was called visitdate - i did order by visitdate desc. so last 5 are the 5 most recent - apologies for confusion

Comment: If the latest five by visitdate works for you, then you can order by visitdate, descending, and limit to 5, as shown by [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101131/2112501)

Comment: See new tag.....

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the last five rows, unless a column provides that information.  Let me assume you have such a column.

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where ht is not null and wt is not null and bmi is not null
order by ? desc
limit 5;
```

Does this do what you want?

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood the question.  You seem to want each column independently.  For this, I think `union all` and `group by` might be appropriate:

```
select max(ht) as ht,
       max(wt) as wt,
       max(bmi) as bmi,
       . . .
from ((select (@rnh := @rnh + 1) as rn, ht, null as wt, null as bmi, . . .
       from t cross join (select @rnh := 0) params
       where ht is not null
       order by ? desc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      (select (@rnw := @rnw + 1) as rn, null, wt, null as bmi, . . .
       from t cross join (select @rnw := 0) params
       where wt is not null
       order by ? desc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      (select (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as rn, null as ht, null as wt, bmi, . . .
       from t cross join (select @rnb := 0) params
       where ht is not null
       order by ? desc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) x
group by rn;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: editted what i meant was the most recent 5 records (e.g. primary key or id or visit date)

Comment: @ValerioZhang . . . Does the edited version do what you want?